# How to access API controller from Spring in HTML

Tags: java, spring

This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/getRandomWildSwimming")
public List<WildSwimming> getRandomWildSwimming() {
    return wildSwimmingService.getRandomWildSwimming();
}
```

How I can access it with HTML? I'm confused, I saw some tutorials where I set `return index.html` for example, but I'm returning here actually service that show me collection data from Mongo in JSON when I send request for example: `http://localhost:8080/wildswimming/getRandomWildSwimming` page show me one collection from mongo in JSON format, how I can show that via html and stylize it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this approach, you need a client. For example, you can use JS or PHP for it.

Then you need to create HTML pages, add scripts (using JS or PHP) to send requests, get responses and show it to user.

This looks like: user opens page -> client sends request to your spring controller -> spring controller returns response -> client gets and shows it to user.

OR

You can use Spring MVC if you do not how to launch client server.

Comment: Can you provide me example with Spring MVC, It seems like that is more better option and easier

Comment: @StephenJankovic What do you use Spring or Spring Boot?

Comment: @SpringBootApplication

Comment: [This link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) may help you. Also I have a repository with Spring MVC project. So you can check [this link](https://github.com/twistedmisted/quiz-website-spring).

Comment: I tried like this `  @GetMapping("/getRandomWildSwimmingMvc")
    public String showHome() {
        wildSwimmingService.getRandomWildSwimming();
        return "hiking";
    }` but im getting Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: Did you create a hiking html page?

Comment: Yeah, and also put that page in both static and template folders inside resource, I put in both just to be sure, and also, my page is blank, but still spring should open it?

Comment: Did you add Thymeleaf dependency?

Comment: ............ Yeah, that was the problem. But why I need that? I didnt read so much about that, as I saw that is something for stylizing pages, why i need that here

Comment: In simple words, Spring use Thymeleaf to display pages. Thymeleaf is template engine. It generates HTML pages. Something like this. That's all I know about it)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a dependency to your project so that spring boot knows how to convert an object into json.  If you're using maven, add com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind to your pom file.

Then, add the @ResponseBody annotation to the getRandomWildSwimming method so that it ends up looking like this...

```
@GetMapping("/getRandomWildSwimming")
public @ResponseBody List<WildSwimming> getRandomWildSwimming() {
    return wildSwimmingService.getRandomWildSwimming();
}
```

This will make the controller respond with json when it is called in a web browser.

Assuming that it returns JSON that looks like this...

[{"rating":89},{"rating":24},{"rating":68}]

You can using the $.get function (from the jquery library), to make a call to the /getRandomWildSwimming api method, which will fetch the JSON and automatically convert it into a javascript array of objects...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="resources/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Wild Swimming Records</h1>
        <ul id="canvas">
        </ul>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.get("./getRandomWildSwimming", function(data) {
                    console.log(data[0].rating);
                    console.log("JSON: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                        $("#canvas").append("<li>" + value.rating + "</li>");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This should result in a page that looks something like this...

```
Wild Swimming Records

    - 89
    - 24
    - 68
```

The first console.log line will take the rating property of the first object in the data array and print it to the browser console.  The second console.log line will convert the entire array back into a json string and print it to the browser console.